# WSDL in node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, wsdl

I have a WSDL file and would like to import it to a NodeJS server application .
Is it possible to do so same as in C# were all the functions are automaticlly created?

I would thank anyone who can teach me the best way to work with NodeJS and soap web services.

Have a great day ,

Comment: Well, [there's `node-soap`](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap).

Comment: Don't use `node-soap` use `strong-soap`, https://github.com/strongloop/strong-soap  an IBM backed rewrite of node-soap.  (This is my opinion, as I ran into debilitating bugs with node-soap.)
Alternatively use java/C# a separate service and use inter process communications.